# postLoad doesn't work, if data are fetched with query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, event-listener, symfony-3.4

I've create the event listener

```
class ProcessPostLoadListener
{
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof Process) {
              .
              .
              .
        }

    }
}
```

When I fetched data with getRepository(Process::class)->find($id), the method postLoad is called, and I can modify data.

But when the data are fetched with the query builder

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('PARTIAL p.{id,answersInRelatedQuestionnaires}')
    ->where('p.id = :processId')
    ->setParameter('processId', $processId);
```

postLoad is not called. What can I do? Is there an another event to listen?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without the partial keyword?

Comment: yes, I have  tried both

Comment: could you dump the result you are getting from this query?

Comment: I do $processes = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);



  "id" => "2000020"
  "model" => null
  "offeredModels" => array:2 
  "opportunity" => "0.00
  "price" => null
  "processValue" => null
  "mUuid" => "8846bd22-4da4-4db1-a64d-d647dfd34a9f"
  "reason" => null
  "rejectReasonText" => null
  "signatureDate" => null
  "answersInRelatedQuestionnairesCopy" => []
  "notes" => null
  "updatedAt" => DateTime @1543414004 
  "answersInRelatedQuestionnaires" => array:54 

]

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from Doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> PostLoad event occurs for an entity after the entity has been loaded into the current EntityManager from the database or after the refresh operation has been applied to it

That means that PostLoad event is only dispatched when an entity object is hydrated, and that is true only when hydration mode is set to HYDRATE_OBJECT. Since you are using HYDRATION_ARRAY, an associative array is being returned and no entity object is being hydrated, that is why PostLoad event doesn't occur.

Comment: Yes, I understand. In my case, it is just an array, And it has nothing to do with the entity process

Comment: Is it possible to write a listener for the hydration mode HYDRATION_ARRAY?

Comment: Generally speaking, you could create a custom symfony event listener and dispatch your custom event. This is the case for whatever event you would like to create, not only for your ARRAY_HYDRATED_EVENT you want. There is nothing built-in in Doctrine to support array hudration events.

Comment: How to crate an event to dispatch when the data were read from the DB?

Comment: tha's a different question, I cannot answer it in a single comment. Moreover, if my posts answered your questions please mark them as accepted, to help more people here :)

Comment: In my case I am doing a findOneBy and it seems to be failing randomly. I solved it by performing a refresh